# Read only data via Spring + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

Noticed that if I want to read some data and if I do not have a transaction context I will not be able to do so because

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

For reading data , is not required a transaction normally.

So in order for Spring to manage the session it needs to have a transaction even for read only operations like selects... ?

Is that not an overhead ?

PS.I do not want to open and close session manually...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Transactional` tells spring to open and close a session, in addition to instructing it to start and commit a transaction. This is not very straightforward, but that's how it works. So if you don't have `@Transactional`, no session gets opened. Here are your options:

- use `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` - the purpose is to have a read-only transaction. I recommend that one
- use JPA `EntityManager` injected with `@PersistenceContext`. It will open a new underlying session for each invocation. Not that good option. But you should consider using `EntityManager` with a readOnly=true transaction
- Use an additional aspect/interceptor/filter to open and close session. That would be hard, and you may end up confused by the spring implementation of hibernate's current session concept.

Comment: I use Spring + Hibernate (without JPA).Now for reading some data and in order for Spring to manage the session I need to use @@Transactional.I have the option for me to open and close the session manually, but i think is not elegant ?!.But I have this thing in mind that usign @@Transactional even with read only .it is the same as not using read only and there is some potential overhead..

Comment: readonly is effective only when you want to prevent writing data as far as i know..http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1/index.html

Comment: don't worry about the overhead, even if there's any.